# Alternative to calling a thread in class constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class that is being accessed by multiple threads.. I wanted the class to do something
before it can respond to call (getSomething).

I was thinking of starting my SampleThreadinside the class constructor but I dont like the idea of firing up a thread inside
a constructor.

I am thinking of doing something like this but I am not sure if this is correct.
The first thread that will call getSomething on my class will start a thread..

But I am still unsure if this is correct..I worry that multiple SampleThread will run and I wanted it to run only once.

```
public class A{
    private final AtomicBoolean isReady = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    public A{

    }

    public void getSomething(){
        if(!isReady.get()){
            new SampleThread().start();
        }
        //continue with the rest of the method
    }
}

public class SampleThread{
    public void run(){
        //Do some long running task once done
        isReady.set(true);
    }
}
```

I dont have a way to add a method called start() where I could call my SampleThread since this is being called by the framework.

Any hints?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried a sample class to simulate this, and I used a latch to wait for my InitializerThread  to finish.

```
package com.race;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class TestRaceCondition {

    public static class SampleClass implements Runnable {
        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        private final AtomicBoolean isReady = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        public void doSomething() {

            synchronized (this) {
                if (!isReady.get()) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is initializing the system....");
                    new InitializerThread(latch).start();

                    try {
                        latch.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    isReady.set(true);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Doing something...." + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Still doing something...." + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
//          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :: is running!");
            doSomething();
        }

    }

    public static class InitializerThread extends Thread {
        private CountDownLatch latch;

        public InitializerThread(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Simulate some long running task
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is calling a long running task....");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            latch.countDown();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleClass myClass = new SampleClass();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(myClass);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(myClass);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(myClass);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(myClass);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

But I am not sure whats wrong with the result..

```
Initializing system....
Calling a long running task....
Initializing system....
Doing something....Thread-0
Still doing something....Thread-0
Doing something....Thread-3
Still doing something....Thread-3
Calling a long running task....
Initializing system....
Doing something....Thread-2
Still doing something....Thread-2
Calling a long running task....
Initializing system....
Doing something....Thread-1
Still doing something....Thread-1
Calling a long running task....
```

It seems that it is still calling my intializer thread multiple times...
I added the latch but something is wrong with my output.

I was expecting something like this...

```
Initializing system....
Calling a long running task....
Doing something....Thread-0
Still doing something....Thread-0
Doing something....Thread-3
Still doing something....Thread-3
Doing something....Thread-2
Still doing something....Thread-2
Doing something....Thread-1
Still doing something....Thread-1
```

**UPDATE 3**
I edited the code as per recommendation to include the synchronize...

```
Thread-0 is initializing the system....
Thread-4 is calling a long running task....
Doing something....Thread-0
Still doing something....Thread-0
Doing something....Thread-2
Still doing something....Thread-2
Doing something....Thread-3
Still doing something....Thread-3
Doing something....Thread-1
Still doing something....Thread-1
```

I just don't get the output..why Thread-0 is doing the initialization but Thread-4 is running the task.  I was expecting the first thread to do the initialization and calling of the long running task.

Comment: I don't understand this question - at all.  I just find it a total mess and have downvoted (and voted to close) in consequence, sorry.  It's a bit depressing to see something like this from such a high rep user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way has a race condition :

```
public void getSomething(){
    if(!isReady.get()){
        new SampleThread().start();
    }
    //continue with the rest of the method
}
```

This is atomic :   `if(!isReady.get())` but the body of the conditional statement associated to is not :

```
{
    new SampleThread().start();
}
```

So you could start twice this thread.

Synchronizing the logic prevents the race condition. It will also increase the number of potential locks on the object but as `if(!isReady.get())` should be fast executed, it should be acceptable.
Note that you probably don't need to use an `AtomicBoolean` if the boolean value is used only in synchronized statements.

So here two ways according to your requirements.

1) To allow the first invocation of `getSomething()` to start `SampleThread`  and that others threads wait for the end of this initialization before executing `getSomething()` :

```
public void getSomething(){
    synchronized(this){
      // init the logic 
      if(!isReady){
          SampleThread t = new SampleThread();
          t.start(); 
          t.join();  // wait for the SampleThread thread termination
          isReady.set(true);           
      }         
      // execute the next only as the init thread was terminated
      if(isReady){
         //continue with the rest of the method
      }

    }     
}
```

2) To allow the first invocation of `getSomething()` to start `SampleThread` and that others threads don't wait for the end of this initialization before executing `getSomething()` :

```
public void getSomething(){
    synchronized(this){
      // init the logic once
      if(!isReady.get()){
          SampleThread t = new SampleThread();
          t.start();                                   
      }                                   
    }
    //continue with the rest of the method       
}
```

And set `isReady` to `true` at the end of `run()` of `SampleThread` :

```
public void run(){
    //Do some long running task once done
    isReady.set(true);
}
```

Comment: Ohh so it means that the first thread that calls getSomething will call my SampleThread() but will it wait for it to finished?

Comment: @Mark Estrada It will not wait as `Thread.start()` returns fast enough and doesn't wait for the termination of the thread. It just says to the JVM to call the run() method of the thread.

Comment: Then is there an option for me to do such that the first thread that will call getSomething will initialize my class...blocks other thread from executing and wait for my sample thread to finished?

Comment: By the way..thank you very much for answering my queries.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: I tried a sample code from what you have suggested..may I ask if there is a workaround or can you point me to the right direction?  Please see my update 2.. As this is almost close to what I am doing.

Comment: You declared  `if(!isReady.get())` before and outside the synchronized statement. So potentially all threads may execute the body associated to.

Comment: Nice answer. If you continue with such content you will sooner or later overturn, and rightfully so!

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry, but I don't get this...can you explain?

Comment: @GhostCat Hello you. It makes 2-3 days that I have the feeling to write silly things on SO. Thanks for giving me some good energy !

Comment: @davidxxx I edited it..but the output still seems a little bit off... Can you see my update 3?  Thanks

Comment: Thread-4 doesn't refer to  `Thread t4 = new Thread(myClass);`. It is the fifth thread you started, that is it refers to the `InitializerThread` instance. Something is not very clear. Do you want that the init thread be started a single time in the whole application lifetime  ? And do you want that threads may execute `getSomething()` before the end of the init ?

Comment: Yes..I want the first thread that accesess my getSomething() method to run my initializer thread...wait for it to finish and then go on with the rest of the code in getSomething(). When a new thread calls getSomething(). It should skip my initializer thread so I was thinking of using the atomicboolean as some flag.

Comment: Ok. It is clearer now. I updated. It should help you I hope !

Comment: @davidxxx oohh...i was confused with thread-4.  So does it mean that my code is now okay? From the output, my initializer thread is called only once. The next threads skips this right? I am just concerned about the synchronized..is this some sort of a performance problem? I noticed that my sysout statements are not randomnized and it seems that only 1 thread is able to execute the rest of my doSomething() code because of the synchronized right?

Comment: Oohh..in OPTION 1.. Can I removed the if(isReady) outside of the synchronized block? I think i am liking this approach..